# Starting Android Emulator fails

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin

Starting android emulator fails with following message

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'ENSAN' 
Failed to create Context 0x3005 
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

What could be going wrong? Any ideas to fix the problem?

Comment: Did you do a google search about the error?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and managed to solve it by installing the latest Windows update. Hope this might work for you.

Comment: edit the answer with the windows update & os details then it would be appropriate

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) .This virtual device is better than built in avd